# Security with cloud functions using parse.com

Tags: javascript, security, parse-platform

I am working with parse.com and looking at making my app secure. I think I have understood well the basics principles of the ACL, CLP, and Cloud functions. My main question comes from [the Part IV of the parse.com blog.](http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/parse-security-iv-ahead-in-the-cloud/). By using a cloud function, I should be securing my app, but what prevents someone to call this cloud function multiple time ? 
  The example is the following define in the cloud :

```
Parse.Cloud.define("like", function(request, response) {
  var post = new Parse.Object("Post");
  post.id = request.params.postId;
  post.increment("likes");
  post.save(null, { useMasterKey: true }).then(function() {
    response.success();
  }, function(error) {
    response.error(error);
  });
});
```

This should be used in my JS code as:

```
 Parse.Cloud.run('like', {postId : theIdOfMyPost}).then(function(results){
        // ok
    }, function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
```

Now, if someone looks at my code, he will understand quite quickly what is going on, just call/run this cloud function multiple times, and likes on the post will raise. This is not much of a big deal here, but this could lead to a security breach in more complicated app I believe ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Behind the scenes, Parse surely has load balancing measures in place to throttle consecutive requests from a single source, usually to increase quality of service as well as detecting and preventing DDos attacks.

The scenario you provided can be prevented using good design on your part. For dealing with having multiple likes from a single user, you restrict a user to be able to Like something only once. Generally you do not let anyone to manipulate your counter directly and increase/decrease this counter only as a by product of a user's action.

Lets say a user likes a photo in your app. In your database, every user object has a `Like` Relation (which acts kind of like a high-performance list) that keeps track of what photos he has like so far. Every time he likes a photo, you go through this list and if the photo is not in there, you add that photo to this Relation and then bump up the photo's Like counter. When he unlikes the photo, you perform the opposite. This way not only your app can scale up reliably, your counters will not be open to abuse by a malicious user.

Comment: Ok, I understand that I'd not increment a counter directly and that would only be a result of something else. Also, I could keep track of which IdUser has liked which photoId, but that would mean that I need to check this Link each time someone likes a photo. If a malicious user calls the cloud function thousands of times, this Relation check will still be made, even if this'll not increment the counter. So this could probably leads to millions of requests. For each modify/add call,I need a kind of check to make sure the action is legitimate, would that be the best way to handle this problem ?

Comment: If you do not have strident security requirements, I think the best thing to do is to avoid any premature optimisation for bottlenecks which do not exist based on hypothetical malicious users. I am not saying you should ignore it and it will not happen but it is better to spend your time developing a better app instead.You can force a user to like something only once per second by keeping a timestamp but I leave this to the later stages of development when you have evidence that your functionality is being exploited.

Comment: That makes sense with what we were thinking, thank you again for your expertise.